# ngrok error page: Failed to complete tunnel connection

Tags: http, server, localhost, ngrok

[image]

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While I was working on a Rails app I wanted to run it on **ngrok** but I got same error below:

`The connection to http://xxxxxx.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3000.`

It seems like ngrok works fine but my local server is not. Which is true since I forgot to run my rails app first by run `$ rails s`. By doing so I was able to get ngrok tunneing works fine.

Make sure your local server run first.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

ngrok shows this error when the local server is not running
start your server first and also check the server port as well as ngrok port

For example: i am using two servers WAMP && XAMPP
WAMP is on port 80
While
XAMPP is on port 8012

therefore the command will be

ngrok http 80 for WAMP folder
ngrok http 8012 for xampp folder

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error even though my local server was running.

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite launch.local:80
```

It helped when I changed it to

```
ngrok http -host-header=launch.local 80
```

Answer (score 0):

First start your local server before you running ngrok.

eg:- I start my local server via apache `service apache2 start`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:
Try explicitly setting the localhost IP by using the command ngrok http 127.0.0.1:8000 (if you have an external server, you can do :port) instead of ngrok http 8000.
If that doesn't work, this article can also help https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/fixed-ngrok-access-to-ngrok.io-has-been-denied/.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

> `http ngrok 80`

its Work For Me

Answer (score -1):

your service API,WebPAge, whearever you have on port 7898 is not running

Answer (score -1):

***For Linux***:

```
./ngrok http 7898
```

It will work!